# Angular 2+: Dynamically set CSS width, of element based on available real estate

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I consider how effectively set in Angular 2+ width of element. I would like firstly to check available real estate in parent element and than appropriately set width of child elements to fit equally this available space in its parent.

1. how could I listen on width change events of parent element?
2. how to check this width?
3. then I could make some calculation of elements width to fit requirements of component user
4. then change width of element to calculated value.

I have tried to use CSS3 and Media Queries but it makes my Component to tightly coupled to certain sizing precondition and makes my angular component not general-purpose.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to start trying to do your own layout calculations. And it is almost never necessary with the appropriate CSS, which can include percents, `calc`, and flexbox.

Comment: If you really need to, you could look at [element queries](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries).

Comment: Yeah but without my own calculation the angular component is not so easily reusable. Then its not just case of use it set max-cols number for my gird of cards and min-length required for this cards and it works, then each time for each use case you must manually do you own custom CSS to fit actual needs of the page. Then component isn't of general purpose, easy to use but its, just the first draft to start the designing of  entirely new component based on current by modifying CSS files, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ngStyle` on the child elements. The [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html)'s example:

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}">...</some-element>
```

You'd be responsible for retreiving/calculating the `widthExp` variable up-to-date from the parent component.

Comment: Ok I think I have achieved this

Answer (score 1):

My solution finally was :

1. add (windows:resize) event binding:
2. and element reference #gridElement in HTML template

   ```
   <div class="grid" (window:resize)="onResize($event)" #gridElement>
   ```
3. Then inside component class I need to Inject this guys:

   ```
   protected _changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef; 

   @ViewChild('gridElement') gridElement: ElementRef;
   ```
4. Make sume helper variables

   ```
   public gridCardWidth = 0;
   public gridCols = 0;
   ```
5. Write function adjusting size of each grid-card element

> ```
> adjustCardWidthToAvailableEstate() { 
>         var gridWidth : number = this.gridElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
>         var newGridCardWidth = this.calculateCardWidth(gridWidth);
>         this.gridCardWidth = ((newGridCardWidth - this.GRID_CARD_MARGIN_LEFT)/gridWidth)*100; // [%]
>         this.gridCols = Math.floor(gridWidth/this.gridCardWidth);
>
>         // refresh list of cards based on content objects
>         this.contentObjectsObservable = Observable.of(this.contentObjects);
>     }
> ```

**Important here is this line of getting grid container width:**

```
var gridWidth : number = this.gridElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
```

The rest is just the logic of calculation.

6. Then call this grid-card size adjusting function in this methods:

   ```
   ngOnInit(); ngAfterViewChecked(); onResize();
   ```
7. In `ngAfterViewChecked()` I need to inform that adjusting of size has happened **changeDetector** object like this

   ```
   this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   ```
8. Lastly I have a width style binding on grid-card element in HTML template

   ```
   <grid-card ... [style.width.%]="gridCardWidth"></grid-card>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code in the component where you want.

this code is an example to set a div width from the component.

```
var x: any = document.getElementById('myDivID');
 x.style.width = '250px';
```